# UnicodeDecodeError while cursor.fetchall()

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, encoding, webapp2

I was trying to export some data from Google Cloud SQL database to an excel file using Python xlsxwriter , **webapp2, appengine** in a deferred task.

The data to be written has to be retrieved from the database.

The query is executing fine but when I try to fetch the data from the query either using **cursor.fetchall()** or by **iterating over cursor** it is throwing the following error:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 4: invalid start byte**

The stacktrace is :

```
 for row in cursor:
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 689, in fetchone
self._FetchMoreRows()
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 606, in _FetchMoreRows
self._DoExec(request)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 448, in _DoExec
return self._HandleResult(response.result)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 487, in _HandleResult
new_rows = self._GetRows(result)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 532, in _GetRows
tuple_proto.values[value_index]))
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 402, in _DecodeVariable
 return converter(value)
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/converters.py", line 126, in Str2Unicode
 return unicode(arg, 'utf-8')
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 4: invalid start byte
```

The same code works if I try to locally run it using MySQLdb instead of rdbms.

There could be some encoding issue in data but that should come up while writing to the file.

I tried finding some data that may be corrupt but was not able to find any.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have text that is encoded in utf8.  What is it encoded in?  If it is latin1, the the `9F` stands for `Ÿ`; would that make sense?  Find the line with the hex 9f; let's see the context.